# Push Notification Device Token?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, token, apple-push-notifications

How to get Device Token from my iPhone Device?

Answer (score 14):

this method will print the deviceToken in console in debug mode, if you want to see the device token you can see in UIAlert also.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"APN device token: %@", deviceToken);
    NSString *deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
    UIAlertView *deviceTokenAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Device Token"
                                                            message:deviceTokenString
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Do you know if this device token can change over time, for an iPhone, or is it constant ?

Comment: I have always observerd that device token is constant, but I think it may change also.

Comment: check the answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927011/is-the-device-token-as-unique-as-the-device-id, it says only when you restore backups will the device token change.

Comment: Note that this will only get called if you call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
   registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
   (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | 
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | 
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];` first.

Answer (score 7):

If you have implemented this method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

}
```

for Push Notification then you will get the device token (This method is actually one of the two methods that you require to implement in the application)

This might find it useful http://urbanairship.com/docs/push.html

you can also look at [Push Notification in Iphone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558645/push-notification-in-iphone-application)

I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 6):

This method will show your device token in console.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken { 

    NSString *str = [NSString 
                     stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
    NSString *newString = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newString forKey:@"deviceToken"];



    NSLog(@"Your deviceToken ---> %@",newString);

}
```