# Push notification on iphone applications

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How to do push notification on iphone?what are the steps for implementing push notification in iphone application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Push Notification in Iphone application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558645/push-notification-in-iphone-application)