# Push Notification Problem

Tags: iphone

I want to get the reminder at each notification comes from the web service in the application for the different tasks. For that what i have used the following methods.
but i am not getting push notific

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err { 
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Push Notification in Iphone application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558645/push-notification-in-iphone-application)

Answer (score 1):

Receiving push messages in the app
So what happens when your iPhone receives a push notification? There are three possible situations:
The app is currently running in the foreground. Nothing happens on the screen and no sound is played, but your app delegate gets a notification. It is up to the app to do something in response to the notification.
The app is closed, either the iPhone’s home screen is active or some other app is running. An alert view pops up with the message text and a sound is played. The user can press Close to dismiss the notification or View to open your app. If the user presses Close, then your app will never be told about this notification.
The iPhone is locked. Now also an alert view pops up and a sound is played but the alert does not have Close/View buttons. Instead, unlocking the phone opens the app.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a lot of problems on Push notification. Please note: if you are not getting the device token back, check to make sure the device is connected to the internet. If not device cannot contact the APN server. It took me days to find this out