# pop-up notices for your iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, push-notification

Hi gentlemen (and gals)!

I'd really appreciate any insights here....

We all know bout the in-app popups that say "Confirm if the XYZ app can use your location" or other things. These are like windows of notices that pop up in-app.

I'd like to be able to 1. choose a user of my app 2. send them a in-app popup message of my choice anytime... ALL done from server-side after the app is already distributed on the Appstore

Hypothetical example ....So an example of this is i can see a user who has not filled out their profile and we (from admin side) can send them a in-app popup that says "User, please fill out your profile!". Just an example.

Client-side wise.... What would we need to do in XCode (what libraries, etc) before we submit it to the appstore? To allow our serverside to do this anytime later?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's call "Push Notification" that you can choose specific user with device UDID.

You can also study from these [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558645/push-notification-in-iphone-application).

Comment: Can the server side send these out randomly anytime in the form of a custom text pop-up window box? I know the server can via alerts and badges anytime

Comment: @xrave3 Of course, you can send any text-message as you prefer. so, you can catch the message from the method name 'didReceiveRemoteNotification' from 'UIApplicationDelegate'. The receive data from notification is NSDictionary form that you can find your message from server.