# How to get device Id of the Iphone

Tags: ios4

I am want to use push notification, I need to get device token of the iPhone.

How to get this, so that I can this in the code.

Comment: Maybe redundant to http://stackoverflow.com/a/7614566/1758762

Comment: I want this without any code.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are referring to the UDID (Unique Device Identifier)

1. Launch iTunes and connect your iPhone.
2. In the right pane, locate the information about your iPhone, including its name, capacity, software version, serial number, and phone number.
3. Reveal the Identifier by clicking on Serial Number
4. Copy the Identifier to your clipboard by choosing Edit → Copy